# Discharging an assumption in Isar

Tags: isar, natural-deduction

In Isar, one can make an assumption and then use it as a premise for an implication goal later.

```
assume PropositionVar
   ...
have "PropositionVar ==> Statement" by (rule impI)
```

In natural deduction with pen and paper, you would *discharge* the assumption then: you can use your assumption only once.

In low-level HOL4, there's an explicit DISCH tactic for this.

What is the case in Isar? Does it have the concept of discharge?

Comment: The Isabelle snippet looks kinda awkward, since when you `assume` some formula, it is not available to `rule` for it to be introduced as an antecedent. Actually, you obtain the (meta) implication when closing that block right after obtaining `Statement`